# SQL SERVER 2008: Trying to insert multiple rows using 1 SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to insert 50+ rows into an SQL server 2008 and am getting a weird error. Please help!

Table Design:

- Name: mod_Facilities
- Columns

  - faclityID, Primary Key/Index
  - facilityName, nvarchar(4000)
  - facilityDescription, nvarchar(4000)
  - statusComment, nvarchar(4000)
  - isPublic, bit
  - isActive, bit
  - isDeleted, bit

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Here's my SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO mod_Facilites (facilityName,facilityDescription,isActive,isDeleted)
VALUES
('Conference Room Lower','Conference Room Lower – 25, (AV ready for meetings and info sessions)','true','false'),
('Conference Room Upper','Conference Room Upper – 21, (AV ready for meetings and info sessions)','true','false'),
('Meeting Room A','Meeting Room A – (upper theatre set up capacity  40) ','true','false'),
('Meeting Room B','Meeting Room B – (AV ready classroom set up capacity  25) ','true','false'),
('Meeting Rooms A & B','Meeting Rooms A & B – (AV ready capacity 80)','true','false'),
('OP Resource Room','OP Resource Room','true','false'),
('Climbing Wall','Climbing Wall','true','false'),
('Bouldering Wall','Bouldering Wall','true','false'),
('Entire Climbing Area','Entire Climbing Area','true','false'),
('CPR/First Aid classroom','CPR/First Aid classroom','true','false'),
('Lobby Area','Lobby Area','true','false'),
('Studio 1','Studio 1 ','true','false'),
('Studio 2','Studio 2','true','false'),
('Studio 3','Studio 3','true','false'),
('Studio 4','Studio 4','true','false'),
('Mat Studio','Mat Studio','true','false');
```

Comment: For those unfamiliar, this is valid syntax in SQL Server 2008. But for previous versions of SQL Server, you have to use a different approach.

Comment: any reason you are passing varchars for isActive and isDeleted?

Comment: What if you generally try `('Mat Studio','Mat Studio', true, false)` (no single quotes around your BIT values) - does that change anything??

Comment: Make sure the tool used to run this is a 2008 tool. I've run into behavior like this when developing against SSMS 2008 but having the resulting script run with sqlcmd for 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged this question as SQL Server 2008, but this is exactly the error you'd see if you tried this syntax on 2005 or earlier.

As an alternative, try:

```
INSERT INTO mod_Facilites 
    (facilityName,facilityDescription,isActive,isDeleted)
    SELECT 'Conference Room Lower','Conference Room Lower – 25, (AV ready for meetings and info sessions)','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Conference Room Upper','Conference Room Upper – 21, (AV ready for meetings and info sessions)','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Meeting Room A','Meeting Room A – (upper theatre set up capacity  40) ','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Meeting Room B','Meeting Room B – (AV ready classroom set up capacity  25) ','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Meeting Rooms A & B','Meeting Rooms A & B – (AV ready capacity 80)','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'OP Resource Room','OP Resource Room','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Climbing Wall','Climbing Wall','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bouldering Wall','Bouldering Wall','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Entire Climbing Area','Entire Climbing Area','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CPR/First Aid classroom','CPR/First Aid classroom','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Lobby Area','Lobby Area','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Studio 1','Studio 1 ','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Studio 2','Studio 2','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Studio 3','Studio 3','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Studio 4','Studio 4','true','false' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mat Studio','Mat Studio','true','false';
```

Comment: While this may well address the problem in the OP. I would be more concerned with why MSSQL 2008 is not acting like MSSQL 2008.

Answer (score 5):

Are you running in sql 2008 compatibility mode?

Does this return 100 or less than 100? If it is less than 100 then you are not running in SQL 2008 compatibility level

```
SELECT compatibility_level 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason it has to be one statement? I have never seen this kind of use of an INSERT statement before. I would either use multiple statements or a [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) or SSIS.

Comment: Do you have an example of a bulk insert?

Comment: link to MSDN added - it depends on the source of your data as to whether it's best to BULK INSERT or SSIS but basically BULK INSERT will insert the contents of file into a table. SSIS can stick anything, anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deal with this is to change the VALUES into SELECTs and UNION them:

```
INSERT INTO mod_Facilites (facilityName,facilityDescription,isActive,isDeleted)
 SELECT 
  'Conference Room Lower', 'Conference Room Lower – 25, (AV ready for meetings  and info sessions)','true','false' UNION ALL
 SELECT 
  'Conference Room Upper','Conference Room Upper – 21, (AV ready for meetings and info sessions)','true','false' UNION ALL
```

... etc